# UITableview Problem with button image

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

my problem is i have one tableview displaying four cells, in those cells i have one cutom button also. By clicking on that button the button image has to be changed like checkmark image.

i tried but not getting properly. my req is if i click on cell at index zero that index button image has to be changed.

can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get the output?If you need any help ask me freely

Comment: please look at the answer which I have given

Answer (score 1):

write the selectedIndex in .h file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(selectedindex==indexPath.row){
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                //here you can change the backgroundimage.
button]setbackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.Jpg"];
}



    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do two things

1. You need to pass a msg to button

   ```
   [comboButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
   [comboButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
   ```
2. and in tableView delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: set the button state to Highlighted

Comment: Thanks for your replay Amit.i wrote below code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath for index 0 but if i click on index0 last index image is changing. if i changed to your code nothing is happening

My code is:

if (m_checkButton.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]) 
   {
    [m_checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   else 
   {
    [m_checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }

Comment: for that button action i used same statements and that was working fine. without this statement i can't change the button image to checked and uncheked image tha's way i added the condition

Comment: for that do this ..... [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
 [btn setHighlighted:YES];...
this works fine and i have tested it

Comment: but not working for me. image at that is not changing some other image is changing